# how to get key and value of Tags of a vm in azure seperated by line?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-functions, inventory

This script can fetch some specific details of the vms including the values of the Tags of a VM. But i would like to have the Values as well as the Keys in this format in a csv file:
Key           Value
Department    MyDepartment
Application   MyApp1
Created By    MyName
Environment   Production

$virtual_machine_object = $null
$virtual_machine_object = @()

```
#Iterating over the NIC Interfaces under the subscription

foreach($azureNICDetail in $azureNICDetails) { 

    #Fetching the VM Name
    $azureVMDetail = $azureVMDetails | ? -Property Id -eq $azureNICDetail.VirtualMachine.id

    #Fetching the VM Status
    $vm_status = get-azvm -ResourceGroupName $azureVMDetail.resourcegroupname -name $azureVMDetail.name -Status

    #Fetching the VM Tags
    $vm_tags = ($azureVMDetail.Tags.values) -join ';'

    #Fetching the VM Size
    $vmsize = Get-AzVMSize -VMName $azureVMDetail.Name -ResourceGroupName $azureVMDetail.ResourceGroupName | ? {$_.Name -eq $azureVMDetail.HardwareProfile.VmSize}

    #Fetching the OS Diks Size in GB
    $OsDisksize = $azureVMDetail.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB

    #VM Details export
    $virtual_machine_object_temp = new-object PSObject 
    $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "name" -Value $azureVMDetail.Name
        if($vm_status.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus -eq "VM running") {
        $vm_status.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus = "active"
        } else {
        $vm_status.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus = "offline"
        }
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "status" -Value $vm_status.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "role" -Value $role
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "cluster" -Value $cluster
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "tenant" -Value $tenant
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "vcpus" -Value $vmsize.NumberOfCores
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "memory" -Value $vmsize.MemoryInMB
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "disk" -Value $OsDisksize   
        $virtual_machine_object_temp | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "comments" -Value $vm_tags
        $virtual_machine_object += $virtual_machine_object_temp
```

}
#Report format and path

```
$virtual_machine_object | Export-Csv "C:\Users\JOHN\Desktop\Inventory\Final Scripts\VM_details_$(get-date -f dd.MM.yyyy).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Seperated by line? Is this what you are expecting https://i.imgur.com/3rMplJl.png

Comment: Yes exactly. i am totally new to scripting thats why dont know the right terms. Appologies

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and I have followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-9.0.0) :

```
(Get-AzVM -name rithwikvmm).tags
```

[image]

rithwikvmm is name of the VM